# How to configure caddy to deliver static file for specific url?

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

I have created a api platform project with the [API Platform distribution](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/tree/v2.6.8).

It comes with a caddy server with a configuration like this:

```
{
    http_port {$CADDY_PORT}
    # Debug
    {$DEBUG}
    # HTTP/3 support
    servers {
        protocol {
            experimental_http3
        }
    }
}

{$SERVER_NAME}

log

route {
    root * /srv/api/public
    mercure {
        # Transport to use (default to Bolt)
        transport_url {$MERCURE_TRANSPORT_URL:bolt:///data/mercure.db}
        # Publisher JWT key
        publisher_jwt {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_ALG}
        # Subscriber JWT key
        subscriber_jwt {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_ALG}
        # Allow anonymous subscribers (double-check that it's what you want)
        anonymous
        # Enable the subscription API (double-check that it's what you want)
        subscriptions
        # Extra directives
        {$MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES}
    }
    vulcain
    push

    # Add links to the API docs and to the Mercure Hub if not set explicitly (e.g. the PWA)
    header ?Link `</docs.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation", </.well-known/mercure>; rel="mercure"`
    # Disable Google FLOC tracking if not enabled explicitly: https://plausible.io/blog/google-floc
    header ?Permissions-Policy "interest-cohort=()"

    php_fastcgi unix//var/run/php/php-fpm.sock
    encode zstd gzip
    file_server
}
```

With this configuration all the incomming http requests are handle by my `index.php` (which is the default file for [file_server](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/file_server) directive) file at the root directory `/srv/api/public`.

I want to configure caddy to prevent the request to be handle by the `index.php` file when the request start with `/file`. This way in my `/srv/api/public` I can create a folder `file` and directly request the images I will put in with request like: `http://localhost/file/my-image.png`

How can I change my caddy file configuration to do that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to use the [`handle_path`](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/handle_path) directive:

```
{$SERVER_NAME}

log

# add this directive
handle_path /file/* {
    root * /srv/api/public/file
    file_server
}

route {
    root * /srv/api/public
```